# GetBoundingClientRect is not a function when mapping array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, array.prototype.map, getboundingclientrect

I'm currently trying to write a script that will mute/pause video offscreen and play/unmute the ones on screen. The Ids of the different videos are mutable 1, mutable 2 etc.

In the code below I start of by getting the nodelist of all the ids beginning with mutable and change that into an array equal to the global variable 'nodelistToArray' when the page loads.

```js
var nodelistToArray;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  nodelistToArray = [document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="mutable"]')];
})
```

Then I have a new function that runs when the user scrolls. Firstly I use .map to log all the values of the arrray into the console, this works fine. It logs this:

```
NodeList(2)
0:video#mutable1
1:video#mutable2
```

but then when I try to use getBoundingClientRect on  each of the elements in the array it gives the error 'el.getBoundingClientRect' is not a function.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  nodelistToArray.map(el => console.log(el))
  nodelistToArray.map(el => el.getBoundingClientRect());
```

I have also tried doing `getBoundingClientRect` on just one query selector on its own and it works fine.

Comment: Try `nodelistToArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="mutable"]')];` instead

Comment: @aerial301 this works great now. Just curious what the 3 dots do that changes it? I noticed it on other things but just thought it was how they formatted it in the answers

Comment: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). What you did is just put the nodelist (which contain the elements)  inside an array so the array only contain one element which is the nodelist while with the spread operator you unpack what is inside the nodelist into the array. You can also verify that by checking the array length `nodelistToArray.length`

Comment: @aerial301 ahhh. thanks